# Decimals not displaying with XSL transformation

Tags: xslt, xpath, solr

The background for this is that I am working with Solr search results. The results are returned in XML. I am using an XSL transformation to display the results.

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Latitude</th>
<th>Longitude</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<xsl:for-each select="response/result/doc">
<xsl:sort select="str[@name='Name']"/>
<xsl:sort select="int[@name='Age']"/>
<xsl:sort select="???[@name='lat']"/>
<xsl:sort select="???[@name='lng']"/>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="str[@name='Name']"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="int[@name='Age']"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="???[@name='lat']"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="???[@name='lng']"/></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
```

I had originally indexed every field as string. Once I changed it and indexed the numbers as integers they didn't display in the output. I completely guess and went with int since I indexed them as integers and it worked. ;)

Here are the data types I'm indexing the latitude and longitude with in Solr:

```
<field name="lat" type="latLongDouble" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="lng" type="latLongDouble" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

I am not sure of any of the proper XSL datatypes that can be used for the "???" above.

1. Can you provide me a list of these to try out?
2. Can you provide me an alternative XSL method to display the output?

Many thanks!

Pérez

Answer (score 0):

Nice! Took some time but I figured it out.

```
<doc>
<int name="Age">14</int> 
<str name="Name">Jonh Doe</str> 
<double name="lat">45.17614</double> 
<double name="lng">-93.87341</double> 
</doc>
```

From your XML look at the data type for each element and use that in place of the "???" above.

In my example I would do:

```
<td><xsl:value-of select="double[@name='lat']"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="double[@name='lng']"/></td>
```

Hope this helps someone in the future!

Pérez